# need to fetch specific data from Left outer join

Tags: sql-server

Let suppose i have four table 
Main, Parent , child, parentchildmapping with below Structure

[image]

StageId will be ParentId or ChildId if ConfigTable will column value Parent or Child.

Now i have to perform left outer join on Main table using all other table and wants data like

ResultSet

- MT.ID
- PT.Code
- CH.Code

For eg:-

[image]

then Result should be like

- 1 PT01 null
- 2 PT01 CH01

till now my query was

```
select MT.ID, PT.code, CH.code from Maintable MT
left outer join Parent PT on MT.SatgeId = PT.ID and MT.ConfigTable = 'Parent'
left outer join child CH on MT.SatgeId = CH.ID and MT.ConfigTable = 'Child'
```

right i am getting output like

- 1 PT01 null
- 2 null CH01

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is, what is not working on the query that you have written? What do you expect as a result and what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use mapping table in order to select parent by child. Here is how to do this:

```
DECLARE @mt TABLE(ID INT, StageID INT, ConfigTable VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @pt TABLE(ID INT, Code VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @ct TABLE(ID INT, Code VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @map TABLE(ID INT, ParentID INT, ChildID INT)

INSERT INTO @mt VALUES(1, 1, 'Parent'),(2, 1, 'Child')
INSERT INTO @pt VALUES(1, 'PT01')
INSERT INTO @ct VALUES(1, 'CH01')
INSERT INTO @map VALUES(1, 1, 1)

SELECT mt.ID, 
       ISNULL(pt.Code, ptp.Code) AS PCode, 
       ct.Code AS CCode
FROM @mt mt
LEFT JOIN @pt pt ON mt.ConfigTable = 'Parent' AND mt.StageID = pt.ID
LEFT JOIN @ct ct ON mt.ConfigTable = 'Child' AND mt.StageID = ct.ID
LEFT JOIN @map map ON ct.ID = map.ChildID
LEFT JOIN @pt ptp ON map.ParentID = ptp.ID
```

Output:

```
ID  PCode   CCode
1   PT01    NULL
2   PT01    CH01
```

Comment: hi, is there any alternative way like without joining same table again to achieve that result ?????

Comment: @RamanSingh, you can do with subquery, but this is the standard and straightforward solution.

Comment: k thnx and ur query will be more time efficient(1M records) then sub-query, right?

Comment: @RamanSingh, it depends. I can not tell unless I test it, but I think optimizer will produce same plans for both. At least version with join will be the same or more efficient then with subquery. But I can not tell this will 100% guaranty unless I test it.